# Sails.js. Check if user exists

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js

Hello guys am new to **Sails.js** ( using **MySQL** )
Am trying to find if a user already exists before registration.

Here this is the code:

```
register:function(req, res, next){
    var params = req.params.all();

    User.find({
        or : [
            { usrnm:params.usrname },
            { eml:params.eml }
        ]
    })
    .exec(function (err, user){
        if (err) {
            return res.negotiate(err);
        }
        if (user) {
            res.status(400);
            return res.json('User already exists!');
        }
    });

    User.create(params, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            return next(err);
        }
        res.status(201);
        res.json(user);
    });
}
```

The problem is:

> The response is always "*User already exists!*" with status code - 400

- **If user exists** with the given username or/and email, the above message is displayed regardless and then something is getting logged in the console ( which I dont understand ) and user is not created as in my MySQL those two fields are unique.
- **If user does not exists ** the user gets created behind but it still displays the above message.

> I want to display the message only if user exists (ie if given credentials matches) else respond with 201

Comment: Looks like you are creating the user even if they do exist, you need to put that in an else block after checking if the user does exist

Comment: yea the code is below now....

Comment: tried putting the Creation part inside "else" but the problem remains

Comment: did you try the code below? can you update with your new code?

Comment: I tried the exact code below but it didnt worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
register:function(req, res, next){
    var params = req.params.all();

    User.find({
        or : [
            { usrnm:params.usrname },
            { eml:params.eml }
        ]
    })
    .exec(function (err, users){
        if (err) {
            return res.negotiate(err);
        }
        if (users.length) {
            res.status(400);
            return res.json('User already exists!');
        } else {
             User.create(params, function(err, user){
              if(err){
                return next(err);
              } else {
                res.status(201);
                res.json(user);
              }
           });
        }
    });
}
```

You should call the create user method if a user with those parameters do not already exist, and so should put it inside the callback.

The User.find() function returns an array, so you need to check its length to see if there are any matching objects.

Comment: Nope new user is not getting created still getting the same message but this time not getting any log

Comment: are you getting the 'user exists' message even if the user doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes exactly am getting the message regardless

Comment: thanks, can you pls accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys I figured out a solution, i will put it here in case if it helps someone

```
if (user) { // will be true even if user = [] 
   res.status(400);
   return res.json('User already exists!');
}
```

In case when user is not found in the DB , **user** is **= [ ]** , this means **[ ] != false**
 , hence the message within the scope is getting displayed.